# How to detect file is ready to consume in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel api for my application to huge file processing.

Sample Route:

```
from("file://testa")
.to("file://testb")
.end();

from("file://testb")
.to("xyz")
.end();
```

here before completing first route second route start processing. My requirement is i dont want to use any shcheduling technique, i want to consume data from folder testb only when first route consume. please help me out how to achive this.

Note: i am newbie to Camel Technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the file component page you can see there is an option called `readLock`. The value `changed` might be what you are looking for. There are other options to create locks for the file component to understand when a file is ready.

For more info: [enter link description here](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a direct component in first route just like:

```
<route id="route1">
    <from uri="file://sourceFolder/"/>
    <log message = "fetching from source folder" />
    <to uri="file://intermediateDestination" />
    <log message = "Writing to an intermediateDestination" />
    <to uri="direct:processSecond" />
</route>

<route id="route2">
    <from uri="direct:processSecond"/>
    <from uri="file://intermediateDestination" />
    <log message = "fetching from intermediateDestination" />
    <to uri="file://destination" />
    <log message = "Writing to an intermediateDestination" />
</route>
```